# Spring: How to get bean implementation dynamically?

Tags: java, spring

Let's say we have interface:

```js
public interface IAuthentication { }
```

and two implementations:

```js
public class LdapAuthentication implements IAuthentication {}

public class DbAuthentication implements IAuthentication {}
```

And finally we have a bean that is responsible for processing authentication. This bean should use one of the implementations shown above (based on configuration specified in for example db).

```js
@Service
public class AuthenticationService {
    public boolean authenticate(...) {
        boolean useDb = ...;   //got from db
        //my problem here
        //how to get right implementation: either LdapAuthentication or DbAuthentication?
        IAuthentication auth = ...;
        return auth.authenticate(...);
    }
}
```

**Question:**
How to get the right implementation?

Comment: Inject them both, and use the appropriate one based on the value of the boolean.

Comment: @JB Nizet It sounds like not a bad idea :) upvote

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If parameter value does not change:

```
@Service
public class AuthenticationService {

    private IAuthentication auth;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        boolean useDb = ...;   //got from db
        this.auth = ...; //choose correct one
    }
    public boolean authenticate(...) {        
        return auth.authenticate(...);
    }
}
```

If parameter is dynamic

```
@Service
public class AuthenticationService {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext сontext;

    public boolean authenticate(...) { 
        boolean useDb = ...;   //got from db
        IAuthentication auth = context.getBean(useDb ? DbAuthentication.class : LdapAuthentication.class);       
        return auth.authenticate(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your dynamic solution is the one I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: does the dynamic approach instantiate everything in the  ApplicationContext again? This looks like what I want but there was questions at work about instantiating all of the beans in the ApplicationContext in sereral services that we need this in.

Comment: @SethWinters it will create only required beans (if they are not loaded yet). it will not recreate everything again.

Comment: Thanks @AdamSkywalker! This will greatly improve our flexibility. We were autowiring individual DB interfaces, but that needs a code change for the code snippet. Not we can get it from the AppContext.

Comment: @SethWinters If you don't want to inject the whole `ApplicationContext` you can use `AutowireCapableBeanFactory`